# Logic programming with Mathematica

Tags: logic, education

My question is: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages) says that there is *logic programming paradigm* support in *Mathematica* (like In **Prolog**).

Could anyone provide me with an example of using this paradigm in *Mathematica*?

Comment: See, e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibrary.wolfram.com%2Finfocenter%2FMathSource%2F809%2F&ei=28GdVbS4Oo-1ogSJ1a-4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEXNGE285oQQ2bO-u5QEHVNjz7jPg&sig2=FlDNJhAF3LUnIl0eB3OdCQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cGU), and google papers/articles by *Maeder* and *Marin*, both have done interesting implementations.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @ciao :  you might be interested in [this prolog implementation](http://ciao-lang.org/).  :-)

Comment: Mathematica has some built-in functions that can solve Boolean expressions, like [SatisfiabilityInstances](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances.html) and [SatisfiableQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiableQ.html).